# Equivalence of logic statements and iff

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Are the following equivalent:

(1) $((p\implies q) \implies r)$ $\wedge$ $((r\implies q) \implies p)$

(2) $p \iff q \iff r$?

I thought of writing a truth table, but it'll take a while, so I was wondering if there's a slicker way to prove or disprove the above. All I really care about is if they're equivalent or not.

Answer (score 2):

(2) needs bracketing to be well-formed.

However, suppose $p$ is true, $q$ false, $r$ true.

Then (1) is true (two conditionals with true consequents).

And (2) is false, whether (i) bracketed as $(p \iff q) \iff r)$ or as (ii) $p \iff (q \iff r)$ or treated as (iii) abbreviating $(p \iff q) \land (q \iff r)$

Comment: Aha, so they are not equivalent. Thank you.

Comment: @GrahamKemp (1) I'm not entirely sure it is good to encourage beginners to bracket-drop; (2) suppose p = T, q = F and r = F, then (⟺)⟺ is T and (⟺)∧(⟺) is F; so they are not equivalent.